# How to get folds line numbers

Tags: ace-editor

Is there any way to get line numbers of all lines in editor with "triangle" button (for folding/unfolding) in gutter, no matter if they are already folded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [foldAll](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/3f7f3257770bf0556052cc6b62bf6bdd43b910fa/lib/ace/edit_session/folding.js#L646-L647) function.
Since Ace recomputes fold data lazily, so you can go over all lines and do

```
var foldWidgets = editor.session.foldWidgets
var fw = foldWidgets[row]; // use cached value
if (fw == null) // if it's not there recompute it
    fw = editor.session.getFoldWidget(row);
```